# Number theory formula needed

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

**Problem:** $10$ numbers modulo $77$ are given. Denote them by $a_1, a_2, ... , a_{10}$. I want to find a surjective function $f(a_1, ... ,a_{10})$ with following condition: $f(a_1, ... ,a_{10}) \neq a_i (\operatorname{mod} 77) \ \ \forall i$. Is this possible to express this function in a simple formula, which is convenient to use in a program code?

Comment: Please clarify. Are the numbers $a_1,...,a_{10}$ fixed? What is the domain and the codomain of $f$? Is it integers, or integers modulo $77$? Do you mean that $f(a_1,...,a_10)\neq a_i$ for ALL choices of the initial numbers or just a fixed set?

Comment: Codomain of $f$ is integers, however if it easier to explain, the condition is $f(a_1,...,a_{10})-a_i$ MUST NOT divide $77$ $\forall i$. Yes, it must be for all choices of $a_i$.

Comment: Ah, okay, It was a bit confusing because when you say $a_i$ are given, it usually means they are fixed numbers, not variables.

Comment: There can't be a surjective function. The domain is finite ($77^{10}$) and the codomain is infinite (the integers).

Comment: I actually meant that every integer modulo $77$ will appear in the image of $f$...

Comment: Are you asking if there is a surjective function $f:\mathbb (Z_{77})^{10} \to \mathbb Z_{77}$ such that $f(a) \ne a_i \quad (i \le i \le 10)$ for all $a \in (\mathbb Z_{77})^{10}$? Do you need a formula or an algorithm?